# airnb/javascript: What does this mean: "These methods may be shadowed by properties ..."?

Tags: javascript

I try to understand the following sentence at github airnb/javascript

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--prototype-builtins

> Why? These methods may be shadowed by properties on the object in
>   question

What is meant with "shadowed" in this case?

For easier reference here the full section:

> 3.7 Do not call Object.prototype methods directly, such as hasOwnProperty, propertyIsEnumerable, and isPrototypeOf.
>
> Why? These methods may be shadowed by properties on the object in
>   question - consider { hasOwnProperty: false } - or, the object may be
>   a null object (Object.create(null)).

```
// bad
console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(key));

// good 
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object,key));

// best
const has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty; // cache the lookup once, in module scope. 
/* or */ 
import has from 'has'; 
// ...
console.log(has.call(object, key));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you creating an object

`const anObject = {};`

it almost always has the `Object` in prototype chain. It allow the created object to have access to functions defined in  `Object` like `hasOwnProperty`.

**Shadowed** means a method or a property that defined in the created object has the same name as those functions or properties that in prototype chain.

Example of shadowing:

```
const obj = {};
obj.hasOwnProperty // => ƒ hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }

obj.hasOwnProperty = 'don\'t do this!';
obj.hasOwnProperty // => "don't do this!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider some example below:

```
const object = { hasOwnProperty: false }
console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) // Error: hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

or

```
const object = null
console.log(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) // Error: Can not read property of null
```

So you can understand `shallowed` in this case is your object methods in prototype is shallowed by an object property (has the same name)

Answer (score 2):

See an example. Here I have created an function with name `hasOwnProperty` directly on the my `object`. So it hides the parent version of the `hasOwnProperty`. In it I write a logic which will return everytime `true`. So anybody who will use my object and tries to detect if it has some property in it (he/she doesn't know I have shadowed the base on) he can have a logic errors in his/her code. Because JS will try to find the function first in the object and call that version which actually does another work.

But when you call this `method` from the `Object.prototype`, which is the `correct version` of the method, and pass the context to it, it will work correctly, because it will call the `Object.prototype`s method with name `hasOwnProperty` and just pass this object as the context of the method. So from here is the warning that you must use this methods from the prototype.

Actually you can also change the `Object.prototype` version of the method, but there is a rule, **Not change the prototypes of the built in objects**.

```js
const object = { 
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
      return true;
  }
};

console.log(object.hasOwnProperty('name')); 
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, 'name'));
```

The first `log` says that there is a property `name` in the `object`, but it isn't. This may cause a logic error. The second one uses the correct version and gives a correct result.

Comment: Okay "shadowed" in this context means the method might have been "overriden" (to use other object oriented programming speak). I understand that the object might be null, but how likely is it that the object has that function `hasOwnProperty()` is "shadowed". Is this such a common scenario?

Comment: it is a common scenario. You may create an object with methods and don't know that your method name is the same of the prototype's one. What about null, it means that the object doesn't have prototype and it's methods. And if you call the method(your obj now has not any prototypes), you can have a runtime error